# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'NgxMatCalendar' before initialization?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, ngx-bootstrap, uncaught-reference-error

Why do I get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'NgxMatCalendar' before initialization`?

I use a `shared.module.ts` where I use imports and exports related to me components, and I have my `app.module.ts` where I import the `SharedModule`. However, I have imported the next two thing

```
import { NgxMatDatetimePickerModule, NgxMatTimepickerModule } from 'ngx-mat-datetime-picker';
```

And in my **NgModule imports**:

```
NgxMatDatetimePickerModule,
NgxMatTimepickerModule,
```

But probably something goes wrong and I don't know why.

The errors says:

[image: error]

The codeline in checkout-overview.component.ts:13 is:

```
@Input() cartId: string;
```

The codeline in edit-event-dialog.component.ts:24 is in its constructor parameter:

```
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
```

I have no clue why this goes wrong. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking up the package on npm I found out this is deprecated and they imply switching to @angular-material/...

Maybe you can try that first?

edit:

Author message: Package no longer supported. Use @angular-material-components/datetime-picker instead, see [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-components/datetime-picker)

Comment: Pls move your comment to the answer' body, since it provides a more direct solution.

Comment: @Ondie Thanks for this! I am new to Angular and frontend, so I didn't even know how to look up for this haha. Thanks! It worked.

Comment: @SzymonSeliga Done :) I'm new to contributing thanks for the suggestion